# Fresco custom image decoder resize options are not applied

Tags: android, fresco, facebook-conceal

I have a custom decoder that uses Conceal to load encrypted images from local storage.

Everything *works* (images are displayed) but performance is terrible when loading local camera images since no downsampling or bitmap resizing is applied at all when the actual JPEG decoder does it work.

```
class CryptoImageDecoder(val crypto: Crypto, val poolFactory: PoolFactory) : ImageDecoder {

    val defaultDecoder = DefaultImageDecoder(null,
            Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().platformDecoder,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    override fun decode(encodedImage: EncodedImage,
                        length: Int,
                        qualityInfo: QualityInfo?,
                        options: ImageDecodeOptions?): CloseableImage {

        encodedImage.use {
            val inputStream = encodedImage.inputStream
            inputStream.skip(CRYPTO_HEADER_BYTES.size.toLong()) //Skip header
            val cipherInputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(inputStream, CRYPTO_ENTITY)

            cipherInputStream.use {
                val bytes = poolFactory.pooledByteBufferFactory.newByteBuffer(cipherInputStream)
                val bytesClosable = CloseableReference.of(bytes)
                val clearEncodedImage = EncodedImage(bytesClosable)

                //This is always 1, no matter what resizeOptions I use in the request
                //clearEncodedImage.sampleSize = how to calculate this?
                clearEncodedImage.encodedCacheKey = encodedImage.encodedCacheKey

                return defaultDecoder.decode(clearEncodedImage, bytes.size(), qualityInfo, options)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way the request is done pretty straightforward

```
val request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(attachment.sourceImageUri)
        .setSource(attachment.sourceImageUri)
        .setResizeOptions(ResizeOptions.forSquareSize(300))
        .build()

val controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setOldController(holder.draweeView.controller)
        .setImageRequest(request)
        .build()
```

Why are resize options ignored, is there another option that I am missing for the decoder?

Comment: How did you get the instance of PoolFactory here? I am trying something similar but I am not sure how to get the poolfactory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that resizing is done before decoding (i.e. the image is transcoded to a smaller JPEG) - and only JPEG is supported right now.

Take a look at [ResizeAndRotateProducer](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/73f3a9c9b016995fe4cacc4f548be626083faee5/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/producers/ResizeAndRotateProducer.java#L198).

Comment: Interesting, that seems to be the piece I am missing. Any idea about how to integrate that producer for my decoder? Doesn't look like there is a straightforward way to get a ProducerContext to extract the request from my decoder.

Comment: I think the easiest way for this to work is to supply a custom decoder that decrypts and decodes. We don't have a lot of documentation for this yet, since this is still changing a bit, but you can take a look at the sample app for SVG / Keyframes support. You add a new image format, header checker and then a decrypting decoder that internally forwards to the default decoder once decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example relevant implemetation given by Alexander Oprisnik I got resizing working with my custom decoder, these are the relevant parts of the solution:

```
class CryptoImageDecoder(val crypto: Crypto, val poolFactory: PoolFactory) : ImageDecoder {

    val defaultDecoder by lazy {
        DefaultImageDecoder(null,
                Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().platformDecoder,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    }

    override fun decode(encodedImage: EncodedImage,
                        length: Int,
                        qualityInfo: QualityInfo?,
                        options: ImageDecodeOptions?): CloseableImage {

        var cipherInputStream: InputStream? = null
        var clearEncodedImage: EncodedImage? = null
        var transcodedImage: EncodedImage? = null
        var transcodedRef: CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>? = null

        try {
            val inputStream = encodedImage.inputStream
            inputStream.skip(CRYPTO_HEADER_BYTES.size.toLong()) //Skip header
            cipherInputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(inputStream, CRYPTO_ENTITY)

            val bytes = poolFactory.pooledByteBufferFactory.newByteBuffer(cipherInputStream)
            val bytesClosable = CloseableReference.of(bytes)
            clearEncodedImage = EncodedImage(bytesClosable)

            val dimensions = BitmapUtil.decodeDimensions(clearEncodedImage.inputStream)
            clearEncodedImage.width = dimensions?.first ?: -1
            clearEncodedImage.height = dimensions?.second ?: -1
            clearEncodedImage.rotationAngle = 0

            val decodeOptions = options as? CryptoDecodeOptions ?: error("ImageOptions should be CryptoDecodeOptions")
            val imageRequest = decodeOptions.imageRequest
            val downsampleRatio = DownsampleUtil.determineSampleSize(imageRequest, clearEncodedImage)
            val downsampleNumerator = calculateDownsampleNumerator(downsampleRatio)

            if (downsampleNumerator == JpegTranscoder.SCALE_DENOMINATOR) {
                //No need to apply any transformation
                return defaultDecoder.decode(clearEncodedImage, bytes.size(), qualityInfo, options)
            }

            val outputStream = poolFactory.pooledByteBufferFactory.newOutputStream()

            JpegTranscoder.transcodeJpeg(
                    PooledByteBufferInputStream(bytes),
                    outputStream,
                    0, //Rotation is ignored
                    downsampleNumerator,
                    DEFAULT_JPEG_QUALITY)
            val bb = outputStream.toByteBuffer()
            transcodedRef = CloseableReference.of(bb)
            transcodedImage = EncodedImage(transcodedRef)
            transcodedImage.encodedCacheKey = encodedImage.encodedCacheKey
            return defaultDecoder.decode(transcodedImage, bb.size(), qualityInfo, options)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Grove.e { "Something went wrong decoding the image" }
            throw ex
        } finally {
            cipherInputStream?.close()
            clearEncodedImage?.close()
            transcodedImage?.close()
            transcodedRef?.close()
        }
    }

    private fun calculateDownsampleNumerator(downsampleRatio: Int): Int {
        return Math.max(1, JpegTranscoder.SCALE_DENOMINATOR / downsampleRatio)
    }
}

/**
 * Dummy wrapper that hold a reference to the request that used this options, required
 * to perform jpeg resizing
 */
class CryptoDecodeOptions(builder: ImageDecodeOptionsBuilder) : ImageDecodeOptions(builder) {
    internal lateinit var imageRequest: ImageRequest
}

/**
 * Decoded images need the actual request to determine resize operations since
 * transcoding is not possible with encrypted images.
 */
fun ImageRequestBuilder.buildForCrypto(): ImageRequest {
    val cryptoDecodeOptions = CryptoDecodeOptions(ImageDecodeOptionsBuilder())
    this.imageDecodeOptions = cryptoDecodeOptions
    val request = this.build()
    cryptoDecodeOptions.imageRequest = request
    return request
}
```

The trick is to use `CryptoDecodeOptions` that simply holds a reference to the request that holds the resize parameters. The rest of the code is a simplification of the method `doTransform` from [ResizeAndRotateProducer](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/73f3a9c9b016995fe4cacc4f548be626083faee5/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/producers/ResizeAndRotateProducer.java#L198). Rotation is ignored since my application does not require it.